# Is it appropriate to estimate a Pareto regression's α by maximising R-squared?

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, pareto-distribution, power-law

Fitting a power law regression. What are the downsides of estimating α by maximising the R-squared of (a) the theoretical values output by the regression with the candidate α and (b) the empirical values the model is being fit to?

Also, I estimated x_min using a modified Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for goodness of fit - is it inappropriate to mix these two tests like this?