# How to implement a GLM with Pareto family?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, pareto-distribution

My data fits a Pareto Distribution very well, better than normal exponential, gamma, lognormal, etc.

I am trying to find a way to implement a GLM with a Pareto family flag. Ideally I can then run the model through emmeans.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215587/estimation-of-regression-model-with-error-terms-having-a-pareto-distribution, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71958/is-it-appropriate-to-estimate-a-pareto-regressions-%CE%B1-by-maximising-r-squared, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115754/pareto-two-tailed-glm-regression,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462701/fitted-value-for-generealized-pareto-distribution-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447924/extending-pareto-nbd-model-with-regression, ...

Comment: ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316902/is-pareto-exponential,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31352/comparing-pareto-fitting-methods

Comment: The R package `VGAM`  can be useful, see https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/VGAM/html/gpd.html